# How to covert this binary string to a normal string?

Tags: python, string, binary

I have this binary string and I am trying to convert to a normal string.

```
[b'\xe4\xba\xba\xe4\xba\xba\xe7\xbd\x91\xef\xbc\x8c\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe9\xa2\x86\xe5\x85\x88\xe7\x9a\x84\xe5\xae\x9e\xe5\x90\x8d\xe5\x88\xb6SNS\xe7\xa4\xbe\xe4\xba\xa4\xe7\xbd\x91\xe7\xbb\x9c\xe3\x80\x82\xe5\x8a\xa0\xe5\x85\xa5\xe4\xba\xba\xe4\xba\xba\xe7\xbd\x91\xef\xbc\x8c\xe6\x89\xbe\xe5\x88\xb0\xe8\x80\x81\xe5\x90\x8c\xe5\xad\xa6\xef\xbc\x8c\xe7\xbb\x93\xe8\xaf\x86\xe6\x96\xb0\xe6\x9c\x8b\xe5\x8f\x8b\xe3\x80\x82']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no normal string mode,string is all about *encoding*, and your string in encoded, so based on your terminal decoding or your custom decoding you can get your real string.

As the default encoding of my terminal is `utf-8`,it decode your string with `utf-8` encoding and print the result :

```
>>> s=[b'\xe4\xba\xba\xe4\xba\xba\xe7\xbd\x91\xef\xbc\x8c\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe9\xa2\x86\xe5\x85\x88\xe7\x9a\x84\xe5\xae\x9e\xe5\x90\x8d\xe5\x88\xb6SNS\xe7\xa4\xbe\xe4\xba\xa4\xe7\xbd\x91\xe7\xbb\x9c\xe3\x80\x82\xe5\x8a\xa0\xe5\x85\xa5\xe4\xba\xba\xe4\xba\xba\xe7\xbd\x91\xef\xbc\x8c\xe6\x89\xbe\xe5\x88\xb0\xe8\x80\x81\xe5\x90\x8c\xe5\xad\xa6\xef\xbc\x8c\xe7\xbb\x93\xe8\xaf\x86\xe6\x96\xb0\xe6\x9c\x8b\xe5\x8f\x8b\xe3\x80\x82']
>>> a=s[0]
>>> print a
人人网，中国领先的实名制SNS社交网络。加入人人网，找到老同学，结识新朋友。
```

Or you can decode manually :

```
>>> print a.decode('utf-8')
人人网，中国领先的实名制SNS社交网络。加入人人网，找到老同学，结识新朋友。
```

Comment: Hi, I am using pythond3.4, decode('utf-8) didn't work. Instead, I got this attribute error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Yes, you are right, I fetch the first elements of this list and then it worked with decode method. Thanks.